# Выполнение функции в среде vs 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте! помогите решить проблему с функциями. имеются две функции одна для зашифрования другая для расшифрования обе реализованы на языке С. нужно сделать так чтобы они запускались в среде vs 2010. когда данные функции работают им нужно передавать параметры через argc и argv. мне нужно чтобы я мог сам вводить с клавы то что мне нужно. например: для того чтобы зашифровать/расшифровать файл должно отображаться следующее
введите имя исходного файла: d:\rfc796.txt // ввели имя и путь к файлу который нужно зашифровать/расшифровать. я уже пытался сделать так чтобы самому вводить с клавы то что нужно мне, а не задавать данные заранее в св-вах vs 2010, но ничего не вышло. помогите их переделать так что при выполнении программы в среде vs 2010 на языке С++ они работали.
заменял переменные argc и argv на другие добавлял строчки типа:

```
printf(enter src file name: )
cin >> fname or gets_s(fname)
```

но в результате при нажатии на кнопку F5 отображалось

```
Missing argument. для продолжения нажмите на любую клавишу или
File read error. для продолжения нажмите на любую клавишу
```

данные функции нормально работают с argc и argv, если их запустить через консоль в ОС Линекс и макентош, при том что в этих системах можно реализовать прогу на языке С, а в винде в среде vs 2010 это невозможно поскольку  vs 2010 поддерживает только vc++, vc#, vbasic, vf#
=============================== DECRYPT.C    ===============================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rijndael.h"

#define KEYBITS 256

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
  unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
  int i;
  int nrounds;
  char *password;
  FILE *input;
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    fputs("Missing argument", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  password = argv[1];
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
    key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;
  input = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
  if (input == NULL)
  {
    fputs("File read error", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  nrounds = rijndaelSetupDecrypt(rk, key, 256);
  while (1)
  {
    unsigned char plaintext[16];
    unsigned char ciphertext[16];
    int j;
    if (fread(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext), 1, input) != 1)
      break;
    rijndaelDecrypt(rk, nrounds, ciphertext, plaintext);
    fwrite(plaintext, sizeof(plaintext), 1, stdout);
  }
  fclose(input);
}
```

=============================== ENCRYPT.C    ===============================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rijndael.h"

#define KEYBITS 256

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
  unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
  int i;
  int nrounds;
  char *password;
  FILE *output;
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    fputs("Missing argument\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  password = argv[1];
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
    key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;
  output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
  if (output == NULL)
  {
    fputs("File write error", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  nrounds = rijndaelSetupEncrypt(rk, key, 256);
  while (!feof(stdin))
  {
    unsigned char plaintext[16];
    unsigned char ciphertext[16];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(plaintext); j++)
    {
      int c = getchar();
      if (c == EOF)
        break;
      plaintext[j] = c;
    }
    if (j == 0)
      break;
    for (; j < sizeof(plaintext); j++)
      plaintext[j] = ' ';
    rijndaelEncrypt(rk, nrounds, plaintext, ciphertext);
    if (fwrite(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext), 1, output) != 1)
    {
      fclose(output);
      fputs("File write error", stderr);
      return 1;
    }
  }
  fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: > я уже пытался сделать так чтобы самому вводить с клавы то что нужно мне, а не задавать данные заранее в св-вах vs 2010, но ничего не вышло

Как именно пытался? В чем проблема?

Comment: Код отформатируйте. 

В "правке вопроса" есть кнопочка "**{}**". Выделяете фрагмент текста с кодом мышкой и жмете ее.

Answer (score 2):

Глупостями занимаетесь. Очевидно ведь, что если программа запускается без аргументов командной строки, то параметр argc имеет другое значение. Т.е. проблема здесь:

```
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    fputs("Missing argument", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
```

Я предлагаю этот фрагмент переписать и сделать не выход из программы, а запрос ввода имени файла. Т.е. получится что-то в духе:

```
char filename[255];
...
if (argc < 3)
{
  fputs("Missing argument", stderr);
  printf("Please enter filename:\n");
  fgets(filename);
}
// погнали дальше, теперь имя файла в переменной filename
// чтобы не пришлось думать откуда его брать, скопируем его из argv
// если действительно его задали через командную строку
else
{
   strcpy(filename, argv[2]);
}
...
```